# SQLite EF Design time tools for Visual Studio 2015 doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, entity-framework-6

I use System.Data.SQLite from https://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.98.0/sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.98.0.exe. I have a C# project from VS2013 with EF6 Edmx model and latest System.Data.SQLite NuGet Package but can't update model from the design time tool. So I decide to generate a new one from SQLite Database. I can add a SQLite connection in the Entity Data Model Wizard but can't proceed to the next step. The wizard suddenly quit and leave nothing. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: So is it VS 2013 or 2015?

Comment: If is is VS 2013, pls install the latest EF 6.1.3 Tools MSI

Comment: I'm on 2015 now, the project is from 2013

Answer (score 0):

Some time its throwing that kind of problem better to go with EF5 Edmx model .

than may be it will work.